# How to Optimise this sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

This query is taking 3 seconds and i want to make it run more quickly.
Please provide any suggestions

```
SELECT Concat(e.estimate1, '-', e.estimate2) AS estimateid,
       e.estimatetype,
       e.createdby,
       e.estimateid AS estID,
       e.`layoutnumber`,
       sd.specno,
       sd.samplenumber,
       sd.numberon,
       c.customerid,
       c.custprosname,
       c.`custtype`,
       (SELECT Count(*)
        FROM  (SELECT e.estimate1
               FROM   `simpleestimatedetails` sd,
                      estimatemaster e,
                      `vcustomer_prospect` c
               WHERE  c.customerid IN ( e.customernumber, e.prospectnumber )
                      AND ( e.estimate1 LIKE '%1%' )
                      AND ( sd.`simpleestid` = e.estimateid )) AS counter) AS
       counter
FROM   `simpleestimatedetails` sd,
       estimatemaster e,
       `vcustomer_prospect` c
WHERE  c.customerid IN ( e.customernumber, e.prospectnumber )
       AND ( e.estimate1 LIKE '%1%' )
       AND ( sd.`simpleestid` = e.estimateid );
```

Comment: use [explain](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) to profile your query

Comment: Sorry i don't have that access.I guess the above query doesnot require any description.we just have to use different approach

Comment: Excuse me, you are assigned to optimize a query and you can't run EXPLAIN? How does anyone expect you to do this? Don't you have a development machine where you (have rights) and can test rewrites, indexes and do profiling?

Comment: Yup Thats the case with me.I will put it here as soon as i get it.but till then can't u provide me any suggestions

Comment: Weird four "anwsers" without seeing an EXPLAIN output first..

Comment: Because this doesnot need explaination.Structure is not needed here i guess.

Answer (score 1):

In Your SQL Query the 'Counter' is calling redundant join of multiple table.

Please ignore the counter column and try to fetch the values as total number of rows returned from the SQl query in last.

Hope this will enhance the Query performance. and you will get desired result by following Query

```
select concat(e.estimate1,'-',e.estimate2) as estimateid,
         e.estimatetype,
         e.CreatedBy,
         e.EstimateID as estID,
         e.`LayoutNumber`,
          sd.specNo,
          sd.SampleNumber,
          sd.NumberON, c.customerid,
          c.CustProsName,
          c.`CustType`
             from `simpleestimatedetails` sd,
              estimatemaster e,
              `vcustomer_prospect` c
             where c.customerid in (e.customernumber,e.ProspectNumber)
             and (e.estimate1 like '%1%')
              and (sd.`SimpleEstID`=e.estimateid);
```

note: the total number of rows will give you value of counter

Comment: I am not getting counterId.
Its an important column.please provide some suggestions.

Comment: As suggested, the counter value can be taken in last while processing the value fetched from SQL query. It can be as simple as just calculating the number of rows fetched.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Concat(e.estimate1, '-', e.estimate2) AS estimateid,
       e.estimatetype,
       e.createdby,
       e.estimateid AS estID,
       e.`layoutnumber`,
       sd.specno,
       sd.samplenumber,
       sd.numberon,
       c.customerid,
       c.custprosname,
       c.`custtype`
  FROM estimatemaster e Inner Join
       `vcustomer_prospect` c
    On c.customerid IN ( e.customernumber, e.prospectnumber )
 Inner Join `simpleestimatedetails` sd
    On sd.`simpleestid` = e.estimateid
 WHERE e.estimate1 LIKE '%1%'
```

**Note :** I have removed the counter column. If you are doing it from the some front end end then you can get the counter value by checking `RowsAffected` or `RowCount` or `RecordsCount` or Somthing Similar property of query component.

Comment: How i can get the counter using rowcount?

Comment: Since Your `counter` query is having same `from` and `where` clause as it for Main query. Hence you can just remove that column and use the component's property for `counter`.

Comment: Please tell me something about how can it be done using component's property.Heard of it first time

Comment: What front end you are using? And also please post the code where you are calling your query showed in ur post.

Comment: Leave my answer. If u have Mysql as Front-End means u have the access of some tool which queries ur MySql db. Then as per ypercube's comment in ur post why can't u fire EXPLAIN command?

Comment: My access is limited.Client does not allow us to fire all the queries.

Comment: Still, Somewhere you are going to use 5209 records in application/web-page which will be a result of calling through object/component. Then there will be a property using same you can come to know the `counter` column's value. Why u r taking count separately in query for same output. The same `counter` part is slowing ur performance, I think.

Comment: Also, what is the use of `5209` as `counter` in every records that is also 5209 times.

Comment: Yeah i know that is slowing the performance.But what can i do.Its the requirement.with having counter in the query,i need to optimise the code

Comment: Dear friend what is the Output of counter column?? I guess 5209 in each records. Am I correct @Samir???